# Rails: safe query against stored array

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, activerecord

I am having a problem performing a where query against an array field in my Postgres database.
In my rails app i have a table called `People`. One column in this is called `pets`. Now this column contains array values, ie:

```
["dog", "cat", "fish"]
```

I would like to perform a query that returns all the people that have a pet dog for example.

The solution ive been using so far looks as such

```
People.where("\"pets\" @> '{\"" + checkedPet + "\"}'")
```

where `checkedPet` is a variable and could be "dog" or any other animal.

This works but i feel is vulnerable to a SQL injection problem?
Is this the case? If so what is a better and safer solution to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [ActiveRecord and PostgreSQL guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#array) you can do the following:

```
People.where('? = any("pets")', checkedPet)
```

Or

```
People.where('"pets" @> ?', "{#{checkedPet}}")
```

Comment: that is exactly what i was looking for! Thank so much!!!
One tiny change though, turns out you need an = after ?
As in People.where('? = any("pets")', checkedPet)

Change it to that and i will mark as correct
Thanks again

Comment: @BenEaston: Yeah, that's a typo)

Comment: I didnt think that second method would guard against the SQL injection issue though?

Comment: @BenEaston: it does, since your binding it with `?`.